# Динамическое задание имени дефайна

Tags: c

Допустим у меня есть массив с числами

```
int numbers[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Мне нужно автоматически создать дефайны вида

```
#define DEF_[тут номер дефайна] [какое-либо число]
```

Конечный результат должен выглядеть следующим образом

```
#define DEF_1 42
#define DEF_2 54
#define DEF_3 45
#define DEF_4 98
```

Возможно ли это в C?

Comment: нет, они в момент компиляции просто заменяются, какой вообще смысл от этого? Может вы хотите что-то другое?

Comment: @Komdosh, нет, именно это. Просто мне было бы удобнее создать n дефайнов и позже к ним обращаться.

Comment: ну вы можете написать программу или скрипт, который просто заполнит файл строчками того вида, который вам нужен, а потом скомпилировать вместе с основной программой. Если вам конечно нужно это только один раз.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поскольку это средства препроцессора, т.е. выполняемые до компиляции, то и создавать их тоже нужно средствами препроцессора. Но динамическое создание директив препроцессора препроцессором же не предусмотрено. Да даже если бы и было предусмотрено - откуда брать ваши числа для макросов? Если препроцессор ничего о синтаксисе С вообще не знает?

Так что в лучшем случае - внешняя программа, которая будет это все либо дописывать в ваш файл, либо, что разумнее, создавать внешний, который можно включить через `#include`.

Но я бы всерьез задумался над применением перечислений (`enum`), а не макросов...

Comment: Совсем забыл про enum. Спасибо!